# Python statsmodels - equivalent to R quasibinomial GLM?

Tags: python, r, statistics, statsmodels

I have an example tutorial in R that I'm following for a GLM and they use a quasibinomial family (i.e. a value betwene 0 and 1).

I want to replicate this in python, using statsmodels but I can't see to find the equivalent to the quasibinomial family in statsmodels.

Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

We have a notebook for this now here:

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/6732

Once merged it will be under examples/notebooks/quasibinomial.ipynb

Here's a summary: if the dependent variable for the binomial family is binary and coded 0/1, you will get the usual GLM binomial model.  If it contains real numbers between 0 and 1, you will get a quasi-binomial analysis with the scale parameter fixed at 1.  If you add `scale="X2"` as an argument when calling the `fit` method, you will get the more usual quasibinomial analysis with a scale parameter estimated from the data.  Finally, if you want a quasibinomial analysis with a non-default variance function, you can create a subclass of `varfuncs.VarianceFunction` and attach it to the `Binomial` family value that you pass to GLM.

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated on StackOverflow ... please add some context, at least the key information, in case the link breaks.  Or make this a comment.

Comment: Thanks! That's really appreciated and a huge help.